# react hook based on other hooks' result

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook `useWebApi`, which can call a web api and return the api result.

```js
function useWebApi(method, url) {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios[method](url).then(res => {
      setFetching(false);
      setResult(res);
    })
  }, [url]);
  return [fetching, result];
}
```

and I want to do something like, fetch `url1`, if `url1` is fetched, then fetch `url2`. The two apis are **not independent**, `url2` can only be called when `url1` finish fetching.
so I write the code like below

```js
const url1 = '/login';
const url2 = '/getMyUserInfo';
function App() {
  const [fetching1, result1] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  if (result1) {
    const [fetching2, result2] = useWebApi('get', url2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    {result1}
    {result2}
    </div>
  )
}
```

but hook can not be called inside `if` statement, so I change it to,

```js
const url1 = '/login';
const url2 = '/getMyUserInfo';
function App() {
  const [fetching1, result1] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (result1) {
      const [fetching2, result2] = useWebApi('get', url2);
    }
  }, [result1])

  return (
    <div>
    {result1}
    {result2}
    </div>
  )
}
```

but, there are still problems, I can not render `result2`, because it is inside a nested scope, so how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is to expose a `doFetch` method, etc. that will enable calling the hook manually.

```
function useWebApi(method, url) {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const doFetch = useCallback((fetchUrl = url) => {
    axios[method](fetchUrl).then(res => {
      setFetching(false);
      setResult(res);
    })
  }, [method, url])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      doFetch();
    }
  }, [doFetch]);

  return [fetching, result, doFetch];
}
```

```
function App() {
  const [fetching1, result1, doFetch1] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  const [fetching2, result2, doFetch2] = useWebApi('get');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (result1) {
      doFetch2(url2);
    }
  }, [result1])

  return (
    <div>
    {result1}
    {result2}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: [offtop] + also it'd be better to expose also "cancel request" callback to use that as return value for `useEffect`

Comment: Something to bear in mind is that `useCallback` will `memoize` (cache) the result of the function injected unless its dependencies `[method, url]` change.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but someone might bump into it in the future and it seems to me that none of the answers solve the general problem here (e. g. how to call a react hook when its input is the output of a previous hook).

Don't get me wrong, the answers provided above are good solutions for this particular problem, but can't be applied as a rule.

The solution to the general problem of cross-dependent hook is dividing your component into multiple components and using return statements conditionally.

Firstly implement a new `InnerComponent`, that is going to take the result of your first api call as a prop.

```
const url2 = '/getMyUserInfo';

export function InnerComponent() {
    const [fetching, result] = useWebApi('get', url2);

    return <>{ result }</>
}
```

Then render this new component conditionally, this is allowed.

```
const url1 = '/login';
import { InnerComponent } from './InnerComponent'

function App() {
  const [fetching, result] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  
  if (fetching) {
      return 'Loading...' // Or some actual Loader component 
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {result}
        { result && <InnerComponent /> } // Here you can be sure that the result of the first hook call is obtained
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second call is not dependent on the result value of the first (i.e. they are two independent GET requests) then go ahead and call them both at the top level as expected of hooks and selectively render result two only if result one exists.

```
function App() {
  const [fetching1, result1] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  const [fetching2, result2] = useWebApi('get', url2);

  return (
    <div>
      {result1}
      {result1 ? result2 : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, Drew, I have updated my post, but `url2` have to wait for `url1` finish fetching

Comment: Perhaps you could factor the dependent API call and response into a separate component and selectively render that component only when login is successful.  I don't think it is a good idea to mix login calls *and* fetching user data in the same component.  Maybe you could also also try factoring your `useWebApi` hook to take a dependency array (similar to base react hooks) so the result of the login is a dependency to the second hook call.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe move the condition in to your hook:

```
function useWebApi(method, url, flag = true) {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(flag) {
        axios[method](url).then(res => {
          setFetching(false);
          setResult(res);
        })
    }
  }, [url, flag]);
  return [fetching, result];
}


function App() {
  const [fetching1, result1] = useWebApi('get', url1);
  const [fetching2, result2] = useWebApi('get', url2, !!result1);

  return (
    <div>
    {result1}
    {result2}
    </div>
  )
}
```